# Passing object using story board iOS5

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I am trying to pass an object to a static grouped table view that I have created in story board.

Here is the code that I am using in my first view to push the second view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSLog(@"Row Selected");
        CustomerDetailTableViewController *detailView = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsView"];
        detailView.customer = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
        NSLog(@"%@",detailView.customer.firstName);
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];

    }
```

The NSlog for the firstName is correct but when the detail view is pushed the cells in the detailView are null. I'm probably just missing something dumb but a fresh set of eyes would be much appreciated.

Here is the code for the detailView controller:

CustomerDetailTableViewController.h

```
@class Customer;

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomerDetailTableViewController : UITableViewController{
    Customer *customer;

    UILabel *fullName;
    UILabel *address;
    UILabel *homePhone;
    UILabel *cellPhone;
    UILabel *email;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *fullName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *address;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *homePhone;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *cellPhone;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Customer *customer;
@end
```

CustomerDetailTableViewController.m

```
#import "CustomerDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "Customer.h"

@implementation CustomerDetailTableViewController
@synthesize fullName, address, homePhone, cellPhone, email, customer;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", customer.firstName, customer.lastName];
    address = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/n%@, %@ %@", customer.address, customer.city, customer.state, customer.zipCode];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 12):

So, you have created the two views (the first TableView and the CustomerDetailTableViewController) with storyboards?
In that case, you have to click on the connection line between the two views into the storyboard and set the "Identifier" field, into the section "Storyboard Segue", to something like "setCustomer". Here's a screenshot:
Here a little screenshot:

[image]

After that, you can comment the method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: on the first TableView, and replace with this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"setCustomer"]) {
        CustomerDetailTableViewController *customerDetailVC = (CustomerDetailTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        customerDetailVC.customer = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    }
}
```

Remember to include

```
#include "CustomerDetailTableViewController.h"
```

at the top of implementation file.

I hope this help!

Comment: Very nice answer. However, I had to add `.row` to the index path to get the correct index for the array (I think it was because I was using grouped view)